# Sorting values for every level 1 in pandas multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I'm having a dataframe with multiindex, the first level is an company_ID and the second level is a timestamp. How can I get a rank of all companies depending on their scores, every month?

```
                        Score
company_idx timestamp            
10006       2010-01-31  69.875394
            2010-11-30  73.640693
            2010-12-31  73.286248
            2011-01-31  73.660052
            2011-02-28  74.615564
            2011-03-31  73.535187
            2011-04-30  72.491390
            2012-01-31  72.162768
            2012-02-29  61.637952
            2012-03-31  59.445419
            2012-04-30  25.685615
            2012-05-31   8.047693
            2012-06-30  58.341200
                          ...
9981        2016-12-31  51.011261
            2018-05-31  54.462832
            2018-06-30  57.126250
            2018-07-31  54.695835
            2018-08-31  63.758145
            2018-09-30  63.255583
            2018-10-31  62.069697
            2018-11-30  62.795650
            2018-12-31  63.045329
            2019-01-31  60.276990
            2019-02-28  56.666379
            2019-03-31  57.903213
            2019-04-30  57.558973
            2019-05-31  52.260287
```

I've tried to do:

```
df2 = df.sort_index(by='Score', ascending=False)
```

But it's not getting me what i want.
Would you be able to help? I'm quite new with multilevel dataframes.
Many thanks!

Comment: Explain in more detail "a rank of all companies depending on their scores, every month".

Comment: sort the scores so that I get a ranking every month of companies_IDs

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Every month -> whole ranking of companies' scores

Answer (score 2):

You should swap the index levels to have the month first, then sort by timestamp ascending and Score descending:

```
df.index = df.index.swaplevel()
df.sort_values(['timestamp', 'Score'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

It does not give interesting result with your sample value, because only one company has Score value for one month.

To extract the values for one month, you can use `df.xs(month_value, level=0)` that will drop one level in the multi-index, or `df.xs(month_value, level=0, drop_level=False)` that will keep it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! How can I access all values for each month?

Comment: @mike.depetriconi: I have edited my post to indicate it.